# trying to show and edit some boxes with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i am trying to create divs that are boxes and do the following on them
1) change the background color
2) make them look like a circle
3) create more boxes(divs)
each has a individual button to fire the events but the boxes wont show and the only the second button works,with the console.log and the console doesnt show any errors at all

**here is the html code and style**

```
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" >
    </script>
    <script src="Query_script.js"></script>


    <div class= "packages">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

</div>  



<button id = "change">Turn Colors on/off</button><br>
<button id = "R-border">Rounded Corners on/off</button><br>
<button id = "create">Add an extra box </button> <br>


<style>
.packages{
border-color: black;
border-width: 5px;
height: 75 px;
width: 75 px;


}


</style>
</body>
</html>
```

**and here is the js and query**

```
let pack=document.getElementById("packages");
let rad= document.getElementById("R-border");
let Adder=document.getElementById("create");
let checker=true;






$(document).ready(function() {
$("#changer").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked1");
if (checker==true){
$('.pack').css('background-color','red');
checker=false;
}
else{
    $('.packa>div').css('background-color','white');
    checker=true;
    }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#R-border").click(function(){
if(checker==true){
    console.log("clicked2");
    $('.pack').css("border-radius","50%");
    checker=false;
}
else{
    $('.pack').css("border-radius");

    }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Adder").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked3");
    $('.pack').append("<div>");  

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maintain CSS selector names properly**

I have done some modifications to HTML and javascript. Try this... It's working properly.

```js
let pack = document.getElementById("packages");
let rad = document.getElementById("R-border");
let Adder = document.getElementById("create");
let checker = true;


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#change").click(function () {
        console.log("clicked1");
        if (checker == true) {
            $('.packages').css('background-color', 'red');
            checker = false;
        } else {
            $('.packages > div').css('background-color', 'white');
            checker = true;
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#R-border").click(function () {
        console.log("clicked2");
        if (checker == true) {
            $('.packages').css("border-radius", "50%");
            checker = false;
        } else {
            $('.packages').css("border-radius");

        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#create").click(function () {
        console.log("clicked3");
        $('.packages').append("<div>");

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Query_script.js"></script>
<div class="packages">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<button id="change">Turn Colors on/off</button>
<br>
<button id="R-border">Rounded Corners on/off</button>
<br>
<button id="create">Add an extra box</button>
<br>


<style>
    .packages {
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 5px;
        height: 75px;
        width: 75px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: well it didnt really work on google chrome tab for some reason,but it works here on this browser